# car won't lock, head lights flicker, 2011 chevy cruze

Tags: chevrolet, lights, cruze

I have a 2011 chevy cruze, and a couple of times now when I've parked the car, the lights start flickering and then the automatic locks won't lock. but it worked ok so I didn't think anything of it....

Both head lights have been changed as I thought that was causing the flickering, so and now it happened again where my lights flickered a bit, and auto locks won't work even when I've pressed very hard on my key.... help! ALso, please help in a cheap way as I am dirt broke :(